# Getting UTF8 error in dbWriteTable to MySQL

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to write export csv data into mysql table.  While reading the data into R i have used the following command

```
read.csv("mpnov.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

stored into an object 'df'.

The reproducible example is as follows:

```
structure(list(ARTICLE_ID = c("4.45e+11", "4.45e+11", "4.45e+11"
), HEADLINE = c("TWEET FROM: DHYANI1811", "TWEET FROM: THE_PARALLEL_ME", 
"TWEET FROM: IMRITIKTHAKUR"), AUTHOR = c("DHYANI1811", "THE_PARALLEL_ME", 
"IMRITIKTHAKUR"), CONTENT = c("@myntra Good Morning If you are born poor its not your mistake, But if you die poor its your mistake. -Bill Gates Good Day", 
"@myntra i have been mailing my issue daily since past week.All i get in reply is an auto generated assurance mail. 1st time pissed wd myntra", 
"@myntra I'm a big Arsenal fan & made a big PUMA collection! ‚_ Shared that collection yesterday. Wanna win... ‚_‚_‚_ #myPUMAcollection"                    
), MEDIA_PROVIDER = c("TWITTER", "TWITTER", "TWITTER")), .Names = c("ARTICLE_ID", 
"HEADLINE", "AUTHOR", "CONTENT", "MEDIA_PROVIDER"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

The column CONTENT has special characters which prevents me from exporting this data into mysql.  I have tried setting the utf8 to utf8_general_ci both at the database and table level using the following code.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I have changed the general to unicode in the above codes.

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utfu COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I have tried `SET NAMES cp850`

I have dropped the database and table many times over and tried when creating the database:

```
create database dbname character set utf8;
```

I have also tried the above code by changing `utf8_unicode_ci` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Nothing seem to work. What can I try next?

Comment: hm the `CONTENT` field seems fine as far as being "valid UTF8", i.e. http://hexutf8.com/?q=2e20e2809a5fe2809a5fe2809a5f20236d7950554d41636f6c6c656374696f6e it would seem another issue is at play

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
show variables like ‘character_set_%’;
SET character_set_database=”utf8”;
SET character_set_server=”utf8”;
```

It seems dbWriteTable() has issue by using utf-8 encoding on Windows.

You can also go the other way:

R:

```
dbSendQuery(con,'SET NAMES utf8') 
dbSendQuery(conn,"INSERT INTO tablename(fffff) values('xxxxx')");
```